# what is a software environment?

Tags: architecture

Hi!

I've programmed independently for quite some time now and recently i got a job at a big firm where i have to develop a relatively large web application. What I'm having difficulty with is the idea of software environments.

For example, I'm making a web app where a developer can request (send email to an admin) an application to be put in a different environment. But exactly, what does it mean that an app is put in a different environment? What is achieved by doing it and what exactly is it that the app is put in (rephrased: what components are meant with the term "software environment"?).

I've read that having separate testing and development environments is a good thing so a developer can't, for example, mess up something while the tester is testing, or vice versa. Also, one project can have many different dev environments so one programmer doesn't mess up something for the other. But, how does this exactly differ from using a CVS (this is probably the worst relation ever made), for example? In CVS, several people can download an application to their local machines and then develop and test it. And if HE DID mess up something along the way it's only on his own machine that the app is broken , and he can simply download the correct version again. However, if he already committed the broken app, it's no big deal, because other developers can simply download the older version again.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each environment is a collection of everything it takes to run the system and usually there are 4 common environments(At least in my experience): Development, Test, Staging and Production.  Think of this as a collection of web servers, databases, and anything else needed to make the system work.  Some systems may use multiple web servers or multiple databases.

The difference between this and a code repository is that each environment runs the system and thus each can be running a different version in theory.  Developers work in their environment, Testers work in theirs, Staging gets used just before releases into Production to ensure nothing breaks, and Production is where the end-users work.  The key here is that there could be changes to a database or networking scripts to be run as part of a change and thus it isn't quite like it is all code that can just be downloaded.  Also, don't forget that in production environments you can't just overwrite the data that often so you have to find a way to put in the changes without taking everything down.

Some places may do something like the following when it comes to setting up the environments:

- http://dev.myapp.com - This is what developers may use to go to a continuous integration server as most would use localhost to access the web application on their local machine.
- http://test.myapp.com - This is for the test environment that is separate so that testers can test things without having to worry about developers changing the code all the time.
- http://staging.myapp.com - This is the environment that is the closest to production and is where last-minute tests can be done.
- http://www.myapp.com - This is the production environment.

Think of what is behind each site to make it work and you'd have an idea of what is an environment.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to think this through :D

Answer (score 0):

The way I think of it is: a software environment is to software engineering as a workshop is to a woodworker.